# How to legalize a car in the USA?

Tags: usa, working-visas, driving

I got a TN Visa for working in the USA and I want to take my car with me. I am living in Mexico City and I want to drive my car from that point to Casper, Wyoming. I will be staying for 1 year and I want to know how can I legalize my car (that I bought in Mexico) in the USA? How is this process?

If further details are needed please, let me know and I will try to enrich this question.